# Get time and number of OBIEE 12c users login

Tags: oracle, logging, authentication, obiee

My requirement is just to monitor and know how many a user log in per month.I need to count number of logins for a user with the time they login

Can anyone please help me in how to do this?

Is there any log file such as obis1-query log file for queries processing monitoring in OBIEE to get these info?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to share with you my finding about my question which has asked. As you may know, OBIEE repository tables, which can be used to show to end users as subject area that this is usgae tracking utility, just track information around sent queries to BI server and not more about users specifically. In this occasion, you can use a method which called enhanced usage tracking for OBIEE that is presented completely here: https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/enhanced-usage-tracking-for-obiee-now-available-as-open-source/

This is exactly what you want. All detail information about users activities in OBIEE and even some redundant ones. You can create a physical table, then add it to repository file and display as subject area to end user with any permission. Of course, according to your software environment or implementation structure, you are supposed to make some changes in this manner.

I hope this goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with obiee and if users log in via a connection pool, but if they log in as an Oracle defined user ID, you want a System Trigger in PL/SQL:

```
create trigger user_logged_in
    after  logon database
begin
    insert into some_audit_table 
       (user_id, login_time) 
       values (sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'), sysdate);
end;
/
```

Not tested, but that should give you a start.  Above example derived from [Oracle PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99885) Example 9-21.

Answer (score 0):

User tracking is your friend. You can set up to log information in the OBIEE RCU database (that database you create/configure as part of OBIEE installation), and it includes the login information. Look how to set up it in Oracle documentation, as well as blog posts (look for OBIEE User tracking in Google). Keep in mind your OBIEE version, as the details to set it up have changed in different versions, basically it involves two steps:

- Set up the RPD to query to the RCU database and table (mainly, in
  your    XXX_BIPLATFORM DB user, the S_NQ_ACCT table for general
  information,    and the S_NQ_DB_ACCT table for the physical
  queries)
- Modify the OBIEE config file or in the EM Beans (depending on
  your OBIEE version) referencing the RPD Physical layer you have set
  up.

Regards